# How We store Float value in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

```
- (void)buttonSave:(UIButton *)bttnSave
{
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTagLblText];
    [dicStore setValue:lbl.textColor forKey:@"Text Color"];

    // fltValue is float type 
    [dicStore setObject:fltValue forKey:@"font"];

    [dicStore setValue:strtextView forKey:@"Text Style"];
    [arrStoreDic addObject:dicStore];
}
```

If We can store this then any one can help me please do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply:

```
dicStore[@"font"] = @(fltValue);
```

However it's troubling that `dicStore` is an instance variable that you want to store into an array, which leads me to believe you will end up with an array of the same dictionary, containing the same values.

Instead create a new dictionary each time and store it into the array (unless, of course, other code needs to see this dictionary).  The current implementation is very brittle.

Comment: @sumitsingh Oops my mistake.  I didn't realise you don't upvote or accept answers you get.  I won't get involved with you again.

Comment: Why don't you upvote this answer and mark it as accepted then ? It's better for futures SO users who will find this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2], nil],
                       nil];

The above code is used to add float values in Dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableDictionary`, `NSarray`, `NSSet` and other collection classes accept only objects, and a float variable is a primitive. You have to create a NSNumber object from your float :

```
NSNumber * floatObject =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fltValue]
[dicStore setObject:floatObject forKey:@"font"];
```

Using literals, your code can be simplified to :

```
 -(void)buttonSave:(UIButton *)bttnSave
{
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTagLblText];

    dicStore[@"Text Color"] = lbl.textColor;
    dicStore[@"font"] = @(fltValue);
    dicStore[@"Text Style"] = strtextView;

    [arrStoreDic addObject:dicStore];
}
```

To get back the float value, it's pretty simple :

```
NSNumber * floatNumber = dicStore[@"font"];
float floatValue = floatNumber.floatValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"floatProperty":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatValue]};
```